# useRef value In devtools but not logged

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm reluctant to add another question about useRef, though I'm yet to find a useful answer.

For today, not requesting a 'ground-up' react ref explanation, though you're welcome to provide one.

**Problem:**

Current Log Output: `Me`

Wanted Log Output: `Mex`

*How can I log Mex, instead of Me when the textbox contains Mex? Thank you*

Current textbox ref property value as devtools sees it, `Mex`

[image]

Caveat: I can only use refs to get the textbox value to pass to my function

Current Code:

```
const textBoxRef = useRef(null) 


const handleKeyPress = (ch, key) => {
      const textVal = textBoxRef.current.value
      console.log(textVal) //Should be 'Mex', 
      but is 'Me'
  }

    <textbox
    ref={textBoxRef}
    onKeypress={handleKeyPress}
    />
```

Comment: Sounds like the key press event has yet to propagate to the DOM by the time you're doing `console.log`, but by the time you look at the dev tools, it has?

Comment: There is no DOM unfortunately or I wouldn't use a ref to get the value of the form.  This is a library called React Blessed  for building React based TUI's.  React wrapping JS ported Ncurses essentially.  **not a deal breaker**.  It' behaves identical to react

Comment: `react-blessed` being in play would probably have been a salient detail to include in your original post, don't you think? Well – why use a keypress event when you could use a change event (if things are identical to React)?

Comment: I figured it would be a distractor and serve as a prextext to avoid the question.  This is react fiber all the way down.  I said it behaves the same, not is the same. React without the DOM is still React

Comment: Well, I'd say you figured wrong there – with less detail, we need to assume and guess more, and that's no good. Anyway, your example here is not even showing how you use `handleKeyPress`.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? If it's not used anywhere, it's not going to _do_ anything. At this point it would be quite useful if you could supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the full scenario where you're having this issue.

Comment: My bad.  I'm delerious. I accidentlally ommited handleKeypress.  It's there now.  I mistook it for a request for the implementation of the custom hook which I removed because **that** was irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected in my first comment, your `keypress` handler gets called [before Blessed's internals](https://github.com/chjj/blessed/blob/eab243fc7ad27f1d2932db6134f7382825ee3488/lib/widgets/textarea.js#L209) have a chance to act to update `value`, but by the time the dev tools catch up, things are alright again.

It's an ugly hack for sure, but you can use [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#setimmediatecallback-args) to defer your own handling until all of the non-deferred handlers have finished and `value` will have been updated. This self-contained example Works For Me(tm)...

```
import React from 'react';
import blessed from 'neo-blessed';
import * as rb from 'react-blessed';
const render = rb.default.createBlessedRenderer(blessed);

function App() {
  const textBoxRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleKeyPress = (ch, key) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      const textVal = textBoxRef.current.value;
      console.log(textVal);  // scribbles all over the screen, but does so correctly
    });
  }

  return (
    <textbox
      ref={textBoxRef}
      onKeypress={handleKeyPress}
      keys
      inputOnFocus
    />
  );
}

const screen = blessed.screen({
  autoPadding: true,
  smartCSR: true,
});

screen.key(['escape', 'C-c'], function (ch, key) {
  return process.exit(0);
});

const component = render(<App/>, screen);
```

Comment: It's an absolute miracle that you were familiar with the library and ventured to take a crack at it... I'll try it out and if successful I'll issue my mea-culpa along with your check mark. thank you thank you

Comment: To be honest, I'd never used the library before. Should `setImmediate` fail, you could try an even uglier `setTimeout`, but maybe at that point you should just [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) the handling :)

Comment: Holy mackerel. it worked.. so if I wanted to learn more about the fix you applied would the debounce link be a good place to look?  And yes, you were right, I was wrong.  obviously I should have mentioned it was blessed underneath.  thanks again

Comment: Well, the fix really is just a hack to work around the order the event handlers are run. Debouncing would be useful so your custom hook/other service doesn't necessarily get called for _every character_ but a bit later.

Comment: Ok, well really what a show of brilliance to in less than 10 minutes dig into the internals of blessed and pull out the relevant fix.  floored really floored